# How to get row position from sql table in Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need the 'position (row)' from an SQL table using my PHP script. I tested my SQL statement and it worked fine. The output is correct.

My SQL statement:

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
SELECT position, name,cash FROM (SELECT name, cash, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position FROM 'my_DB'.'Cash' ORDER BY cash DESC ) AS t WHERE name = 'user44';
```

Output:

```
"position":44,"name":"user44","cash":"5600"
```

But if i put it in PHP:

```
$query="SET @rownum = 0; SELECT position, name,cash FROM (SELECT name, cash, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position FROM 'my_DB'.'Cash' ORDER BY cash DESC ) AS t WHERE name = 'user44';";
```

it shows me a `errant query`.

I also tried something like this:

```
$query="SELECT position, name,cash FROM (SELECT name, cash, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position FROM 'my_DB'.'Cash' ORDER BY cash DESC ) AS t WHERE name = 'user44';";
```

Output:

```
"position":null,"name":"user44","cash":"5600"
```

Thanks to VolkerK,
i solved that Problem with:

`$query = "SET @rownum =0;";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
$query="SELECT position, name,cash FROM (SELECT name, cash, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position FROM 'my_DB'.'HSCash' ORDER BY cash DESC ) AS t WHERE name = 'user44'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);`

Comment: Why not add a numeric key set to auto increment itself? Why do you need the position? Usually when using a database, you don't care about the storage order.

Comment: It's not one statement but two. Depending on the api you're using to "talk" to the MySQL server you have to send them in separate calls to whatever function/method is used to transmit the actual query.

Comment: @Kulvar i need the position because i want to show the Highscore(cash).

Comment: @VolkerK Thank u a lot now i get the correct values

Answer (score 0):

I understand better now.

The trick is not to get the position, it's to get the number of people that have a better score than the user.

SQL:

```
// Get how much cash the user make
SELECT cash
FROM mydb.cash
WHERE name = :name;

// Get how many people did better + 1
SELECT COUNT(*)+1
FROM mydb.cash
WHERE cash > :cash
```

The contatenated query is more complicated, but didn't need to order the whole table, and looks like

```
SELECT position, name, cash
FROM mydb.cash
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS position
    FROM mydb.cash
    WHERE cash > (
        SELECT cash
        FROM mydb.cash
        WHERE name = :name
    )
)
WHERE name = :name
```

Or, to limit the join by filtering before joining, like :

```
SELECT position, name, cash
FROM (
    SELECT name, cash
    FROM mydb.cash
    WHERE name = :name
)
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS position
    FROM mydb.cash
    WHERE cash > (
        SELECT cash
        FROM mydb.cash
        WHERE name = :name
    )
)
```